# iPhone - how do I know if a protocol method was implemented?

Tags: iphone, class

I have created a class and this class has its own delegate protocol.
Inside that protocol, there's an optional method, declared like

```
@protocol myClassDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) myOptionalMethod;

@end
```

Inside the class I have a call to myOptionalMethod, in the form of

```
[delegate myOptionalMethod];
```

but as the method is optional, if I call this method on a delegate that has not implemented the method, it will crash.

So, how do I test to see if the method was implemented before calling it?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy.

```
if([delegate respondsToSelector:myOptionalMethod]){
    // You can now call this method without a crash
    [delegate myOptionalMethod];
}
```

Comment: great, glad to help (had to beat those others though) luckily.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `respondsToSelector` method to determine if the delegate has the relevant method prior to calling the selector on the delegate.

For example:

```
if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myOptionalMethod)]) {
    [delegate myOptionalMethod];
}
```

Comment: Typo: "to determine if the delete" - > "to determine if the delegate". Good answer otherwise.

Comment: @Greg Gianforcaro Thanks for the heads up. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`-respondsToSelector:` is useful for individual methods, as others have posted here. For a stricter interpretation, you can see whether a class was declared as implementing a protocol with the `-conformsToProtocol:` method:

```
BOOL isAGrommet = [myObject conformsToProtocol: @protocol(Grommet)];
```